# What is the easiest FLV player for embedding video on a website?

Tags: flash, video, flv

I have video that I've converted to FLV format.  I'd rather host it on my own site than use a service like YouTube.  What is the easiest player to use?  I'd like to just put the .swf file of the player somewhere on my server, and give it the video as a parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't tried yet **[Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org)** which seems well documented

it is featured on **[arctic startup](http://www.arcticstartup.com/2009/02/12/flowplayer-the-next-open-source-success/)** and only restriction to use it with opensource licence is to have their logo displayed

Comment: changed this one to accepted answer as I've had problems with OS FLV and it doesn't seem to be maintained anymore. Of course, I only use it now as a backup in case HTML5 video is unavailable. (Which is to say, for IE 6-8 users.)

Answer (score 17):

Take a look at [OSflv](http://www.osflv.com/).

Comment: I like this better than JW FLV player because it has a better-looking default interface, and it doesn't have a restrictive license.

Comment: ... but it isn't perfect - you can get it to pause without changing the play/pause button graphic by clicking and dragging around on the scrub bar.

Comment: urm well this is fine if you're using PHP...

Comment: You don't need PHP. There is a PHP library to generate the embeddable code, but there is also an HTML page that creates the embed code with javascript.

Comment: OSflv doesn't appear to support Safari. (If you care about Mac compatibility.)

Comment: has anyone tried the safari support?

Comment: The latest version seems to work fine on Safari (verified both PC and MAC).

Answer (score 17):

http://flv-player.net/

- Options from minimalist to feature rich.
- Simple but very effective HTML generator lets you play with their code for the demo
- .swf as small as 5KB
- Creative Commons BY SA and MPL 1.1 licences

Comment: Thanks, I like this, I'm going to play around with it some.

Comment: +1 perfect! This is the one I went with after trying all the suggested players in this thread.

Answer (score 10):

JW FLV Player : http://www.jeroenwijering.com/?item=JW_FLV_Media_Player

Comment: This was helpful, but it has a very restrictive license (can't use it on any site that has even AdSense ads).  I liked OSflv better.

Answer (score 1):

This could be the obvious answer but the FLVPlayBack component is really nice if you have a single video you need to throw on a website in hurry.  Drag it on the stage - select a control panel - double click controls to edit with the Flash drawing tools - post to the website.You might have to use a FlashVar to get the url into the url but that's fairly trivial...

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the new open source player directly from Adobe: Strobe Media Playback.  It's totally free and open source, BSD license.
Has plugins for commercialization and CDN. has youtube plugin. You can easily create new themes.

However - documentation at this point is not very good.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many FLV players and i came across Applian FLV Player. this one has got to be my best. it is light weight, its free comes with an optional audio recorder and no spyware or such. [check it out here](http://www.applian.com/flvplayer/)

With this however you will not be able to embed it into your regular web page.

Comment: Sorry, my original title wasn't clear.  I'm not looking for a player to watch videos on my PC, but a SWF file I can put on my website.  I've updated the title to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm personally a big fan of JW, though I've heard Floplayer is good too.  JW has an enormous number of features and has a very clean interface.  It takes less than a minute to set up a video online; I host all my videos myself, mostly video game clips and x264 demos.  ([Example 1](http://mirror05.x264.nl/Dark/Flash/mof.html) [Example 2](http://mirror05.x264.nl/Dark/Flash/index_lowbitrate.html) [Example 3](http://mirror05.x264.nl/Dark/Flash/sademo.html) [Example 4](http://mirror05.x264.nl/Dark/Flash/extra.html) [Example 5](http://mirror05.x264.nl/Dark/Flash/psytouhou.html))

Answer (score 0):

I use [JW FLV Player](http://www.jeroenwijering.com/?item=JW_FLV_Media_Player) and it's very good.
It also supports FLV streaming so if you use mod_flv with Lighttpd for example you can make you own little youtube.
There's also a [mod_flv for apache](http://www.mosalov.com/wiki/Flash_streaming_with_mod_flvx#Install_mod_flvx) and you also can use a [php](http://xmoov.com/xmoov-php/)(or any language of your choice) script to enable streaming.

Answer (score 0):

[Any FLV Player](http://www.any-flv-player.com), compact easy to use