# playing .SWF file in ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net

I am able to convert video files in .flv format but I am not able to play the file in .aspx page.

Do I also need the relevant .swf file in order to run the .FLV file or only .flv is sufficient?

In either case, please provide with the solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a flv movie to an ASP.NET page is in no way different from adding one to a html page. Check [play flv in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248800/play-flv-in-html) to get an idea.

You do *not* need the swf.

Alternatively, of course, you can use YouTube: http://www.youtube.com/youtubeonyoursite

Comment: Hi...thanks for your help...it works :) ....however I also wanted a free player so I have used http://www.aspnetflashvideo.com/aspnetflashvideo_Default.aspx