# How to play flv stream in HTML page not specialy creating SWF app?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, flv

How to play flv stream in HTML page not specialy creating SWF app? So I heard there is some way just using some html code to  create SWF inside HTML page just for FLV playback...

Is it possible, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000" id="obj1" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" border="0" width="550" height="370"
    param name="movie" value="URL of FLV file"
    param name="quality" value="High">
    embed id='embed' src="URL of FLV File" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" name="obj1" width="550" height="370"
object
```

i m not sure if u are looking for this

Answer (score 1):

You will need a Flash movie in any case, but most Flash-based video players accept specifying the movie to play using a parameter, without the need to build the movie yourself.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99406/what-is-the-easiest-flv-player-for-embedding-video-on-a-website) for a good list of such Flash-based video players.