# embed .f4v video in html

Tags: html, video, embed

How can I embed .f4v video in HTML. Please guide me to the right direction

Comment: Are you willing to use a flash video player to embed the FLV?

Comment: I have edited my post. I think, the method tried is wrong. Is it possible to show this Video in my web page ? I have few .f4v videos in my server

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the easiest FLV player for embedding video on a website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99406/what-is-the-easiest-flv-player-for-embedding-video-on-a-website)

Comment: you will need a Flash player. See the duplicate link

Comment: Thank you. Your guidelines helps me to find a solution. I have embedded the Video with OS FLV player.

Answer (score 0):

I was always searching for Embed Code to play .f4v Video. But that was wrong. Actually it needed to download a Flash Player to play this Video. Mr Pekka helped me to understand that concept.  I used the Flash Player: http://www.osflv.com/Download.html