# how i embed flv player &.flv file in html?

Tags: html, flvplayer

js file & event on which div box is open now instead of empty div box i want to play .flv files that i download from you tube so how do I embed flv player & its control & play my .flv file in that player?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best free open source FLV player (embed)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823866/what-is-the-best-free-open-source-flv-player-embed)

Comment: also [What is the easiest FLV player for embedding video on a website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99406/what-is-the-easiest-flv-player-for-embedding-video-on-a-website)

Answer (score -2):

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="400" height="350"
wmode="transparent" data="flvplayer.swf?file=**vid location**&autoStart=true">
<param name="movie" value="flvplayer.swf?file=**vid location**&autoStart=true" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
</object>
```