# How to upload and stream video using Appengine Blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, video, streaming, blobstore

I'm using Google Appengine to upload and serve photo images, but I would also like to do the same with audio and video files. Does anyone know any way to do this? Please let me have sample code if you can. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blobstore is suitable for any kind of file. It has no special affinity for images. The same upload and download handlers you use for images can be used for audio, video, or any other type of file.

Streaming a video to a user has more to do with what kind of file you upload, and how you embed it on your website. You can upload an FLV video and embed an [FLV player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99406/what-is-the-easiest-flv-player-for-embedding-video-on-a-website) on your site, or try the [HTML5 video](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video) tag.