# Amazon EC2 or Google App Engine - Video Upload, conversion and serving

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-ec2, google-cloud-storage

I'm starting a new project that will mainly involve the following:

- uploading a large quantity of videos
- converting them
- serving them to users

I'm looking into Google App Engine and using the new [Google Cloud storage API](https://developers.google.com/storage/) to store the videos.

But the Google Could storage API is still [experimental with Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/) which is a bit scary.

But i'm wondering if the EC2 from Amazon will not be a better choice, because it's more mature and may be more adapted to that kind of service that i'm trying to build.

Comment: You could use the blobstore if you're worried that Cloud storage API will change too much. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/

Comment: Also,what are your metrics for defining "best choice"? Is it cost, ease of use?

Comment: Ease to use first and then cost

Comment: Ok, check this post too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157014/how-to-upload-and-stream-video-using-appengine-blobstore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First choice would be neither.

Video transcoding is fairly CPU intensive.  You'll want to use an optimized transcoder that takes advantage of the transcoding features on newer CPUs or GPUs.  Neither EC2 or GAE will let you do this, since they don't reveal what hardware you're running on.  You might consider using a cloud based transcoding service instead of doing it yourself.

In this you'd mostly be storing and serving. and Amazon is cheaper for storage and bandwidth.

Given the question I'm assuming you're no expert on transcoding.  You wouldn't be writing your own Go transcoders, so in that case Amazon would be your only option to run some open source transcoder.

Answer (score 3):

Well from memory this was the exact demonstration from this years Google IO, using App Engine combined with [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/products/compute-engine) to do uploads + transcoding + other goodies.

[Here's](https://www.brightcove.com/en/blog/2012/07/first-look-at-google-compute-engine-for-video-transcoding) a blob post for example with some details.

[Here's](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ws2VRHq5ars) one of the presentations from I/O.

Comment: Oh i watched a lot of Google IO this year but i missed this one i guess! thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Web Services recently released a new web service called [Amazon Elastic Transcoder](http://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder).

Comment: As a note, footers are generally frowned upon here, particularly if they link back to your website. I've removed them from your last two answers.