# How i can put the video showing image in front of image using jQuery css in html?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

as example i need to put the image in center of image as http://www.press75.com/themes/video-elements-theme-demo/

on the web-page code check that page exist with video or not if yes then they wrap the image with anchor tag

```
<img src="myimage" alt=""/>
```

if image found that it's goes like

```
<a href="embedelink" id="videofound">    <img src="myimage" alt=""/></a>
```

now if link open that open a fancybox who show the video in it. now i have a problem that someone can show me the css that it's show the  play image in middle of image as demo shows.

how i  can put the css than their is no problem come. well in m case the image is bigger then `height="367" width="550"`

can somone show me the css for that.

thanks

Comment: need to compute left and top dynamically using width and height of available area

Comment: tell me a thing that how i can fit the play image over my image using css. can you show me some code in css. maybe calculate over the example width and height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Jquery Have a look at http://fancybox.net/

code extract from http://fancybox.net/howto

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* This is basic - uses default settings */

    $("a#single_image").fancybox();

    /* Using custom settings */

    $("a#inline").fancybox({
        'hideOnContentClick': true
    });

    /* Apply fancybox to multiple items */

    $("a.group").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :   600, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'overlayShow'   :   false
    });

});
```

Comment: I think play icons along with other buttons are normally provided and are configurable by video poviders like youtube vimeo etc ..

Comment: play icon putted on the video content they served. i need to put the play icon on the image who i served from the code. because i have no control on mockup i need to do this using jQuery and Css.well thanks for help

Comment: how are you trying to play it then ? have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99406/what-is-the-easiest-flv-player-for-embedding-video-on-a-website ?

Comment: we show the video in iframe and video come from Youtube and other's site who give facelity to put them in iframe.the thing i need that put the play icon on center of image first of post