# Inserting video on webpages

Tags: html, video, embed, flv

What possibilities are there for inserting and showing videos on a webpage that

- don't require additional plugins or installations from the user and
- can be used for other than the .flv format (.f4v, .avi e.g.)

At SO I found a few questions like this: [stackoverflow.com[...]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99406/what-is-the-easiest-flv-player-for-embedding-video-on-a-website), but they are only about .flv-players. Is that because there is nothing else?

I know there are many, many formats and no tool can handle them all. But is it at all possible to show *any* other than .flv formats without extra plugins? I have never found any.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/

It also has a `wmv` player: http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-wmv-player/

Answer (score 2):

Most latest technology is **HTML5** with `<video>` tag

The `<video>` tag specifies video, such as a movie clip or other video streams.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

[Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/)

Now most of the browsers supports **HTML5** so no worry of using + don't require additional plugins or installations