# HTML Play Video

Tags: html, video

I need some advice on how to play video on a website.  What I would like is to have a clip link on the page, and upon being clicked, a video player expands to the middle of the screen and plays the video (and has the standard video player controls).  It also has "X" to close the video.  I would suppose there is a widget or tool for this but I can't seem to find it.

Also what video resolution and format would be best (most compatible with browsers)?  The video would just be a local file on the server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting video on webpages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668117/inserting-video-on-webpages) and [many others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=html+video)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try look here:

http://rainbow.arch.scriptmania.com/scripts/music/video.html

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_videos.asp

http://www.sothinkmedia.com/guide/makebutton.htm

Hope this helps.