# Embed streaming FLV H.264 MPEG-4, MPEG AAC in HTML

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I can paste a live-streaming URL in VLC and it plays. Here is the media information provided by VLC:

[image]

The URL is of the format http://***.flv I am assuming this is FLV container. But I can only guarantee what I see in the screenshot above.

It is possible to embed this live streaming video in HTML which will work on modern Chrome and/or iOS/Safari devices?

This is the code I tried:

```
<video controls id="video" width="320" height="240" preload autobuffer >
     <source src="http://***.flv" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

In Mac/Chrome this only attempts to download the "whole" file. Of course, the file is infinite, so this will never actually play.

Comment: afaik you can't play a .flv container in the `<video>` element, you will need to use an HLS stream for live video

Comment: I am seeing that it is required to use Flash in this situation. However, there are still simple options, as discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99406/what-is-the-easiest-flv-player-for-embedding-video-on-a-website

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [videojs](http://www.videojs.com), you can use it to stream flv because it mimics the video tag. The following example allows to stream a rtmp live feed inside a html5 video tag.

```
<video id="myvideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
 controls preload="auto" width="320" height="240"
 poster="yourposter.png"
 data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
<source src="rtmp://localhost/live/test" type="rtmp/flv">
</video>
```